# Use AutoIT to select some elements in browser

Tags: windows, browser, automation, autoit

I want to use AutoIT in order to automatically open my browser, visit a website, fill in the form and submit or click some elements in the web page.

```
Local $ccLocation = '%APPDATA%\..\Local\CocCoc\Browser\Application\browser.exe' 
Local $link = 'http://google.com'

Run('cmd')
WinWaitActive('C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe')
Send($ccLocation & '{ENTER}')
```

`$ccLocation` is the path to my `browser.exe`

Now I can open my browser (Chrome) but I don't know how to visit a website or take some actions with this websites. How can I do to continue?

Comment: FWIW: There are a number of webdriver-based solutions (e.g. selenium) in a variety of languages that would fit the bill here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two examples using Internet Explorer. Out of the three most popular browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome) IE is the easiest to automate because it has a built in API that AutoIt can use to automate it. If you are stuck on using Firefox or Chrome you can download and use the AutoIt UDF for them [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/?page=1) and [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/?page=1). They have similar functions to the ones I have used in the examples. A word of warning though. Both the Firefox and Chrome UDF require you to install extra plugins. That means that any scripts you write will be dependent on the browsers having those plugins.

Example 1

```
#include <IE.au3>

SeachForUser("MrAutoIt")

Func SeachForUser($sUser)
    Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://stackoverflow.com/users")
    Local $hWnd = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")

    $oSearchBox = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "userfilter")
    _IEAction($oSearchBox, "focus")
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server; INSTANCE:1]", $sUser & "{Enter}")
EndFunc   ;==>SeachForUser
```

Example 2

```
#include <IE.au3>

SeachGoogle("mary poppins")

Func SeachGoogle($sSeach)
    Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.google.com")
    Local $oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 0)
    Local $oSearchBox = _IEFormElementGetCollection($oForm, 4)

    _IEFormElementSetValue($oSearchBox, $sSeach)
    _IEFormSubmit($oForm)
EndFunc   ;==>SeachGoogle
```

Comment: LOL, look at that polite Example 1... "There's something wrong... in the AutoIt.... Who you're gonna call?"